# how to map an array by jolt, there are keys and values in other 2 elements of input array

Tags: json, jolt

First time JOLT user trying to restructure an array into a similar multi-level array. stackoverflow is asking for less code and more words, so I hope this extra sentence covers that.

**input**:

```json
{
  "data": [
    [         // KEYS
      "key1",
      "key2.subkey2.1",
      "key3.0.subkey3.0",
      "key3.1.subkey3.1"
    ],


    [        // VALUES OF above keys
      "valuekey1",
      "valueSubkey2.0",
      "valueSubkey3.0",
      "valueSubkey3.1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**desired output**:

```json
{
  "key1": "valuekey1",
  "key2": {
    "subkey2.1": "valueSubkey2.0"
  },
  "key3": [
    {
      "subkey3.0": "valueSubkey3.0"
    },
    {
      "subkey3.1": "valueSubkey3.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "0": { // the array already has only one outermost component
          "*": {
            "@(2,[1][&])": "@(3,[0][&1])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "*.sub*": {
        "@": "&(1,1).sub&(1,2)"
      },
      "*.*.sub*": {
        "@": "&(1,1)[&(1,2)].sub&(1,3)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

*where*

**&(1,2)**, as an example, represents the literal replacement for the **2**nd asterisk from the **1** upper level

- in the **1**st spec : Match all the respective counterparts so as to
  stand the value with index **0** vs. with index **1** to form four
  individual key-value pairs
- in the **2**nd spec : Partition the keys by the dots without ignoring the `sub` literals

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's right what im looking for

Comment: Nice to help @mycuser thank u 2